Trouble Replicating SciPy Welch
I'm replicating SciPy's Welch method by hand for the squared magnitude spectrum (not PSD) of a real signal, and I've been successful on everything except for the first two bins. I know you're supposed to multiply everything by 2 for a real signal to make up for the negative frequencies EXCEPT for the first (DC) and last (Nyquist) bins, which you leave as is. This makes my last bin line up with the SciPy implementation, but not my first bin -- or, strangely, my second bin.
scipy.signal.welch(wf, fs=1, nperseg=32768, 
noverlap=int(32768*0.5), window='hann', scaling='spectrum')[1] 

# VERSUS 

def get_welch(wf, shift_prop=0.5, win_type='hann', num_wins=None):
    # Define window length
    n_win = 32768
    n_shift = int(n_win*shift_prop)

    n_possible_win_starts = len(wf) - n_win # Number of samples that could be a start of a sample
    n_full_wins_from_possible_win_starts = np.floor(n_possible_win_starts / n_shift) # Number of full windows we can get out of this set
    max_num_wins = n_full_wins_from_possible_win_starts + 1 # Add one more because the final sample in n_possible_win_starts can always be a sample (though the real start will likely be before this)
    num_wins_final = int(min(num_wins, max_num_wins)) if num_wins is not None else int(max_num_wins) # Use num_wins if provided and valid, otherwise use the maximum number of windows we can get

    window = get_window(win_type, n_win)
    norm = 2*np.ones((n_win // 2) + 1) # Multiply by two for real FFT (only using half the frequencies)
    norm[0] = 1  # ...except for the DC and
    norm[-1] = 1 # Nyquist frequencies
    norm /= np.sum(window)**2 # Squared sum of window coefficients for window normalization (just N for rectangle)

    # Divide the waveform into windows of length n_win, take magnitude of FFT of each
    powers_list = [
        norm*np.abs(rfft(wf[i*n_shift : i*n_shift + n_win]*window))**2 # Each new window has a start index that's n_shift more than the last
        for i in range(num_wins_final)
    ]

    # Average over all windows
    avg_powers = np.mean(powers_list, axis=0)
    return avg_powers

Mine:
[2.33239712e-12 4.95288285e-11 4.12817837e-10 ... 1.48807759e-11 1.56874933e-11 7.94847912e-12]
SciPy:
[2.41470477e-09 1.22107509e-09 4.12817837e-10 ... 1.48807759e-11 1.56874933e-11 7.94847912e-12]

Scipy.signal.welch applies detrending to the data by default.
Disable it and your implementation will match theirs:
scipy.signal.welch(wf, fs=1, nperseg=32768, 
noverlap=int(32768*0.5), window='hann', scaling='spectrum', detrend=False)


This is a key point that’s often missed. Most spectral estimation textbooks assume the signal is zero mean as it simplifies the Wiener Khinchin result
